# Baire sets have arbitrarily fine refinements. Barry Simon. Problem 1 page 239.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Definition (Baire set)  Let X be a compact Hausdorff space. The Baire sets are the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all compacts $G_{\delta}$'s.

Definition (Partition) Given an algebra , $\mathcal{U}$, a partition associated to $\mathcal{U}$, is a finite subset $\mathcal{P}\subset \mathcal{U}$ so that

(i) All sets in $\mathcal{P}$ are nonempty

(ii) $P_1,\ P_2\in\mathcal{P}\Rightarrow P_1\cap P_2=\emptyset$

(iii) $\bigcup_{P\in\mathcal{P}}P=X$

Problem:

Given any open cover $\left\{U_{a}\right\}_{a\in I}$, of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, prove that one can find a partition $\left\{P_j\right\}_{j=1}^{n}$ into Baire sets so that each $P_j$ lies in some single $U_a$.
(Hint: First find an open cover by  Baire sets, $\left\{V_l\right\}_{l=1}^{m}$, so each $V_l$ is in some $U_a$.

I have this...
Let $\left\{U_{a}\right\}_{a\in I}$ open cover of $X$. $X$ is compact, then exists $1,\ldots, m$ such that $\left\{U_{l}\right\}_{l=1}^{m}$ is finite open cover of $X$.

Now, $X=\bigcup_{l=1}^{m} U_l$, and $\bigcup_{l=1}^{m} U_l=\bigcup_{l=1}^{m} U_l\setminus(U_1\cup \ldots, \cup U_{l-1})$ with $U_{0}=\emptyset.$ now this union is  disjoint.

Define $P_l=U_l\setminus (U_1\cup \ldots \cup U_{0})$. This works?...

Comment: No, there is no reason why the $P_l$ you define are Baire sets. What have you learnt about Baire sets? They're Borel obviously. But do you have more info than that on such sets? Start looking there first.

Comment: I only know that the baire sets are in the smallest sigma algebra that contains the compacts formed by intersection of open sets.

Comment: $(U_a)$ open cover of X.
for each $x$, exists $a_x$ such that $x\in U_{a_(x)}$. ${x}$ is closed and $U_{a_x}$ open
By Urysohn's lemma exists $f_x:X\to [0,1]$
${f_x}(y)=1$ over ${x}$ and ${f_x}(y)=0$ over $X\setminus U_{a_x}$
Then $\left\{y:f_x(y)>0\right\}\subset U_{a_x}$

Now, ${y:{f_x}(y)>1/2}$ is open Baire set
Then $V_x=\left\{y:{f_x}(y)>1/2\right\}$ is open cover Baire sets of $X$.
And $X$ compact, then exists $x_1,\ldots,x_m$ such that 
$X=\bigcup_{l=1}^{m} V_l$ with $V_l=V_{x_l}$

Defines $P_l=V_{l}\setminus (V_1 \cup\ldots \cup V_{l-1})$ $V_{0}=\emptyset$
It is work?..